# Android Kotlin findViewById(R.id.btnSave) must not be null

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-studio-2.2

I have created Recycler view and I want to save todo item them. Process is : click on add icon then show another activity which is TaskActivity, Then Enter Task name And Click on Save Button. The error posted below
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: findViewById(R.id.btnSave) must not be null

We have looked at a number of posts and tried a few with no results.

Here is the code for the MainActivity.kt

```
package abc.com.recyclerviewuserinput

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   lateinit var recyclerMain : RecyclerView
  lateinit var layoutmanger: RecyclerView.LayoutManager
 lateinit var btnSave: Button

  val myList = ArrayList<String>()
    // declare variable for the adapter
    lateinit var recyclerAdapter: Adapter  // here Adapter is name of Adapter class
    // lateinit var editTaskName : EditText
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

      //  val view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, container, false )
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        recyclerAdapter = Adapter(this, myList)  //  recycle Adapter
        recyclerMain= findViewById(R.id.recyclerMain)   // Recycler view
      layoutmanger= LinearLayoutManager(this)  // layout manager
    var editTaskName= findViewById <EditText>(R.id.editTaskName)
   btnSave= findViewById(R.id.btnSave)
        btnSave.setOnClickListener {
                myList.add(editTaskName.text.toString() )
        }


        //Now set layoutmanager and recycler Adapter with Recycler view
        recyclerMain.adapter= recyclerAdapter
        recyclerMain.layoutManager= layoutmanger


    }
    fun openNewTask(view: View) {
        startActivity(Intent(this,TaskActivity:: class.java))
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the TaskActivity.kt

```
package abc.com.recyclerviewuserinput

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText

class TaskActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task)
  

    }

  
}
```

Here is the code for the activity_task.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".TaskActivity">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTaskName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Pankaj"
        android:hint="@string/enter_task_name_here"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSave"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/add_to_task" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the code for the activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

    android:id="@+id/recyclerMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="openNewTask"
        android:tint="@color/purple_500"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="23dp"
        android:src="@drawable/add"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the Adapter.kt

```
package abc.com.recyclerviewuserinput

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import org.w3c.dom.Text

class Adapter(val context: Context, val itemList : ArrayList<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.SampleViewHolder>() {


class SampleViewHolder (view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)
    {
    val rowtextView: TextView= view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecyclerRowItem)
}


    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SampleViewHolder {
           val view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent,false)

        return SampleViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SampleViewHolder, position: Int) {
       

        val text= itemList[position]
      
        holder.rowtextView.text= text

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
       return itemList.size
    }

}
```

Why indViewById(R.id.btnSave) must not be null is showing here. I have also tried through lateinit var declare but he was also showing error. So what to do here to reslove.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like btnsave is in activity_task.xml but you are trying to use it in Mainactivity.

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at which activity is btnSave being imported from. Ideally it is best not to repeat id names across activities/fragments.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Brother, you are cant call btnSave button in you main activity because it is not created on the main activity. it is created on activity_task.
Try to create an adapter that inflates the activity_task.xml then do your button thing inside the onbindviewholder